# (C#) Type or namespace list could not be found while using system.Collections.generic

Tags: c#, list, types, namespaces

I have an issue with creating lists in C#. It says that the type or namespace "file<>" could not be found. I am using System.Collections.Generic and creating the list "correct" as far as I know.

I have basically nothing yet besides the list (worked with array earlier but it didn't meet the requirements):

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Week_3_Opdracht_3
{
    class Program
    {
        public list<string> streamReaderResults = new list<string>();


        private static string currentFileLine;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            StreamReader opdrachtDrieFile = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\sande\Documents\VisualStudio school\.txt files to read\Opdracht 3 tekst.txt");

            while ((currentFileLine = opdrachtDrieFile.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                //nothing yet.
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

From what I know, you create a list by typing "list [name of the list] = new list();". However, this doesn't work. Why am I receiving this error message?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Take the [tour] and read [ask]! (Note: the current problem with your question is you just say "this doesn't work")

Comment: Have you taken a look at your project references to see if the assembly is being properly found?

Comment: `List` is case sensitive, so it should be `List<string>` not `list<string>`.

Comment: It also needs to be static if you are accessing it from the static `Main` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C# is a case-sensitive language, so you need to watch casing. Also, `Main` in your program is a `static` method, and can only access `static` members of the `Program` class. So you need to mark the `List<T>` as static:

```
namespace Week_3_Opdracht_3
{
    class Program
    {
        public static List<string> streamReaderResults = new List<string>();


        private static string currentFileLine;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            StreamReader opdrachtDrieFile = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\sande\Documents\VisualStudio school\.txt files to read\Opdracht 3 tekst.txt");

            while ((currentFileLine = opdrachtDrieFile.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                //nothing yet.
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I never noticed List was with a capital 'L'. Thanks :)
I am quite new to programming. My teacher told us to make as least things static as possible. Gonna read up on it soon.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make list to static.

```
public static List<string> streamReaderResults = new List<string>();
```